# Service Activator not completing before next message from JMS is processed

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

The Setup:
I am using Spring Integration to grab messages from a message queue.  The message comes in XML format and a method named parseCustPaymentXML gets called by my service activator, processes the XML message, and stores it in Java objects.  Afterwards, another method named processCustPayment is called from parseCustPaymentXML that takes the Java objects and inserts them to a database.  Below is how I have my inbound JMS and service activator set up...

```
<int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        destination="custPaymentRequestDestination"
        connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
        channel="jmsInChannel"
        concurrent-consumers="1" />

<int:service-activator id="parseCustPaymentServiceActivator"
                       ref="custPaymentService"
                       input-channel="jmsInChannel"
                       method="parseCustPaymentXML"
                       requires-reply="true" />
```

The Problem:
The process does not take long to run, but if a message comes in while parseCustPaymentXML or processCustPayment is still running, the message is pulled and parseCustPaymentXML is kicked off concurrently with the first message process.  This is not the behavior I prefer.  I am wanting for the first message to completely finish before the next message is started (non-concurrent).

Please let me know if more information is required for help.

Answer (score 0):

With concurrent-consumers="1", only one message will be processed at a time; make sure you haven't declared your inbound adapter twice? It's a common mistake - especially in web applications.

Turn on DEBUG logging and all should become clear